# c# mvc apicontroller five table join and return value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

can anyone please tell me, I have already joined five tables and I have tested join is correct. When I debug  up to "Location1" values return.

Also I added return Location1, It says

> "Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

My question is how can I display return valve?

This is my ApiController and class code.

```html
 public class Posts
    {
       
        public Suburb suburb { get; set; }
        public SubRegion subRegion { get; set; }
        public SubRegionDeliveryTime subRegionDeliveryTime { get; set; }
        public DeliveryTime deliveryTime { get; set; }
        public DeliveryPeriod deliveryPeriod { get; set; }

    }



 public IEnumerable<Posts> Get()
            
       {
         
           using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
           {
              
             var  Location1 = (from su in db.TLCSuburb
                                join Subr in db.TLCSubRegion on
                                su.SubRegionID equals Subr.SubregionID
                                join srdt in db.TLCSubRegionDeliveryTime on
                                Subr.SubregionID equals srdt.SubregionID
                                join DT in db.TLCDeliveryTime on
                                srdt.DeliveryTimeId equals     DT.DeliveryTimeId
                                join DP in db.TLCDeliveryPeriod on
                                DT.DeliveryPeriodID equals DP.DeliveryPeriodID
                                orderby Subr.SubregionID
                                select new 
                                {
                                    su.name,
                                    su.postcode,
                                    su.AuState,
                                    su.Latitude,
                                    su.Longitude,
                                    DT.DeliveryDay,
                                    DP.PeriodType,
                                    Subr.CloseDayId,
                                    Subr.SubregionName,
                                }).ToList();

             
            //return null;
            

            return Location1;
 
              

           }


       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this:

```
var  Location1 = (from su in db.TLCSuburb
                                join Subr in db.TLCSubRegion on
                                su.SubRegionID equals Subr.SubregionID
                                join srdt in db.TLCSubRegionDeliveryTime on
                                Subr.SubregionID equals srdt.SubregionID
                                join DT in db.TLCDeliveryTime on
                                srdt.DeliveryTimeId equals     DT.DeliveryTimeId
                                join DP in db.TLCDeliveryPeriod on
                                DT.DeliveryPeriodID equals DP.DeliveryPeriodID
                                orderby Subr.SubregionID
                                select new Post
                                {
                                    suburb = new Suburb(){
                                       Name = su.name,
                                       PostCode = su.postcode,
                                       AuState = su.AuState,
                                       Latitude = su.Latitude,
                                       Longitude = su.Longitude
                                     }, 
                                    deliveryTime = DT.DeliveryDay,
                                    deliveryPeriod = new DeliveryPeriod(){
                                        PeriodType = DP.PeriodType
                                     },
                                    subRegion = new SubRegion(){ 
                                        CloseDayId = Subr.CloseDayId,
                                        SubRegionName = Subr.SubregionName
                                     }
                                }).ToList();
```

You'll have to explicitly convert it to `IEnumerable<Post>` instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. There was few issue it say "<ExceptionMessage>
The entity or complex type 'Ide.Models.Suburb' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
</ExceptionMessage>"

Comment: error massage say An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code. The entity or complex type 'Ide.Models.Suburb' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: When I added your code db.TLCSuburb.AsEnumerable(), It'll works but all the field are missy. Are there any way to display only this data?
su.name,   su.postcode,  su.AuState,  su.Latitude,                                  su.Longitude,    DT.DeliveryDay,    DP.PeriodType,                                Subr.CloseDayId,     Subr.SubregionName,

Comment: I need to only display XML data following fields. What do I have to change my code?                                
<name>ALEXANDRIA</name>
<postcode>2015</postcode>
<AuState>NSW</AuState>
<Latitude>-33.9018818</Latitude>
<Longitude>151.2000103</Longitude>
<DeliveryDay>Wednesday</DeliveryDay>
<CloseDayId>1</CloseDayId>
<PeriodType>weekly</PeriodType>
<SubregionName>Sydney - North West</SubregionName>